# What is the drop ratio among the berries when you spin a PokéStop?

Tags: pokemon-go

With this [particularly half-outdated page](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokestops), it seems like the drop rate of Berries is about 7.5%. But, what is the ratio between Razz Berry, Nanab Berry and Pinap Berry?

Comment: Anecdotally, it was between 2.5:1:1 and 3:1:1 for my last ~2000 pokestop items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/gen-2-pokestop-item-drops-berries-evolution-items-changed/), based on more than 23 700 item drops, **the drop rate of berries has globally increased** with gen 2 and the new berries ! Here are some approximative rates :

[image: berries rate gen 2]

so if we look at the ratio just among berries :

- Razz Berry : 53%
- Nanab Berry : 25%
- Pinap Berry : 22%